# Publishing very specific iOS app on App Store

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

I am working smart lock system which consists of:

- device connected to door
- web administration and API
- Android app
- iOS app
- BLE tags

Device is connected to door. It accepts BLE connection. If authentication is successful door will be unlocked.

Android app, iOS app and BLE tags are used as keys. These apps are very simple and consists of just two buttons for unlock door and call elevator.
Android app has already been developed. It works fine and I don't have problem with distribution. It is not distributed from Google Play. APK file is sent to new users in E-Mail.

However, It is not allowed to distribute IPA files in same way. I found that IPA file can be distributed via enterprise program to users from same company. It is obvious that I cannot use this program because users will not be in same company. Seems that I don't have other option than distributing this app via App Store. I am afraid that Apple will reject my app because it is not useful to majority of store users. 
Does anyone have experience with something similar. If I develop this app and Apple rejects it will be waste of time and money.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because app store submission policy is [off-topic for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165/65839) and better addressed by [Apple support](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/65839).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a hundreds of iOS BLE apps approved and in Apple's App store that are specific to the vendor's BLE device.  You just have to clearly document it as such, and be prepared to answer questions during the app review process (such as sending a BLE device if requested, or doing a demo video, etc.).  The app should be configurable after download from the App store (not customized by you per customer before download).

Answer (score 0):

You can use TestFlight beta testing. It should be regular distribution builds. You are actually submitting the app to the AppStore and it also gets reviewed.

It makes sense because you can invite external users (up to 1000 users) to test your app without having any information about their devices. With ad-hoc builds you must have all devices registered in your dev center account (up to 100 users).

See more from here - [Click here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH8)